# For discrete random variables $X,Y,Z$, what conditions normally might cause $P(Y\mid X,Z) > P(Y \mid Z)$ or vice versa?

Tags: probability

For discrete random variables $X,Y,Z$, I am wondering what conditions normally might cause

$$
P(Y\mid X=x,Z=z) > P(Y \mid Z=z)
$$

at $X=x,Z=z$. Is there a connection with correlation? I know generally that if $Y \perp X \mid Z$, then it holds with equality. However, more generally do there exists paradigms to think about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key idea is that any conditional distribution is itself a distribution.  I.e. if everything is conditioned on $Z$, you might as well consider $Z$ to be your entire sample space.  And if you don't know / can't say anything special about $Z$, then there is no restriction whatsoever on the conditional distribution.

So you're effectively asking: under what conditions $P(Y | X) > P(Y)$?  Well, they are "positively correlated" in a sense, but really, that's not a good answer but merely re-stating the requirement but in a way that is less formal / rigorous.